# Determine range of function differentiating under integral sign

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $$f(x)=\int_x^{2x} (\frac{e^{-t^2x}}{t}) \ dt$$ for $x>0$. Differentiating under the integral sign, or applying Leibniz rule, yields

$$f'(x)=\int_x^{2x} (-te^{-t^2x}) \ dt + \frac{e^{-4x^3}-e^{-x^3}}{x}$$

The first term integral can be evaluated using u-substitution, and then $$f'(x)= \frac{3e^{-4x^3}-3e^{-x^3}}{2x}$$

Where would one go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is very correct.

So, now, you face integrals
$$I=\int \frac{e^{-k x^n}} x \,dx$$ Use
$$k x^n=t \implies x=\left(\frac{t}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\implies dx=\frac{\left(\frac{t}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{k n}\,dt$$ which make
$$I=\frac 1 n \int \frac{e^{-t}} t \,dt=\frac{1}{n}\text{Ei}(-t)$$ where appears the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Back to $x$
$$I=\int \frac{e^{-k x^n}} x \,dx=\frac{1}{n}\text{Ei}\left(-k x^n\right)$$